# is there a way to increase slack notification popup timeout?

Tags: slack

Is it possible to change the Slack notification popup timeout ?
https://slack.com/help/articles/201355156-Configure-your-Slack-notifications

I know I can change its position on the screens.
Sometimes it disappears too fast and hard to find the channel if there are many Slack workspaces are open .

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked on the notification center of your laptop?

If you haven't clicked on the notification toast (pop up), you'll see all your notifications there (on a Macbook: swipe left with two fingers from the right edge of the trackpad, or click the day and time of the menu bar).

If you see a stack of notifications, click on the one on top and it will show every one of them. It works just as the notifications on a smartphone.

Hope this helps and never miss a message ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using windows and the notification center didn't work well.
when I clicked on each on ,it just got disappeared without opening it in Slack.